# Writing a function from a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert the following formula to a function in excel:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(R1C1,10,3,(ROUND((RIGHT(R1C1,3)*29.97)/1000,0))),9,1,"";"")
```

What this does is take a timecode like this: `00:01:35,748` and turn it into this: `00:01:35;22`

I don't know how to put the existing functions into a custom function and what the result would look like.

Comment: It looks like you are converting a time to a frame number (which is why you have the 29.97) right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this is. I'm converting a .srt timecode file to one that's compatible with adobe encore for subtitles.

Comment: Why would you ever want to convert a working formula, into a ***SLOWER*** code form? Just looking to make life harder?

Comment: @user2140261 - I think that a function with a sensible name like `timeCode` is a huge improvement over the one above - readability is better, and less risk of error in copy/paste operations. When it is used many times in the same spreadsheet it will save space (characters), load faster, and might actually be faster. Do you have any evidence for your assertion that VBA is slower than the above formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the VBA editor (Alt-F11), select "insert module" from the Insert menu, then type the following (updated for better code practices - thanks @ja72 for inputs):

```
Option Explicit
Public Const fps = 29.97 ' frames per second

Function timeCode(s)
' take a string as input
' find the fractional time
' and convert to frame number like 00:01:35,748
' and turn it into this: 00:01:35;22

Dim comma, fraction, frameNum, frameInSec

comma = InStr(1, s, ",")
fraction = Mid(s, comma + 1, Len(s))
' convert to seconds regardless of number of digits:
frameInSec = Val(fraction) / (10 ^ Len(fraction))
frameNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(frameInSec * fps, 0)
timeCode = Left(s, comma - 1) & ";" & frameNum

End Function
```

Now you will be able to enter a formula like

```
=timeCode("00:01:35,748")
```

into your spreadsheet, and the result will be

```
00:01:35;22
```

Which is what you wanted...

Instead of the string, you can of course use a cell reference - so if you have `"00:01:35,748"` in cell A1, you can type

```
=timeCode(A1)
```

in cell B1 (for example) and get the result you want. Custom functions - powerful stuff.

**EDIT** by special request (two for the price of one...) : changing the formatting out the output string to replace `:` with `;`, and make the frame number always two digits (with leading zero if needed):

```
Dim tempString
tempString = Left(s, comma - 1) & ";" & Format(frameNum, "00")
timeCode = Replace(tempString, ":", ";")
```

It should be obvious where you put this in the above code...

Comment: That's awesome! But now I have another request. Can we make the function do this: take 00:00:00;0 and turn the colons into semi-colons (I was just doing a find and replace before) and then force the final 0 to always be in the format of 2 digits so a ;4 would always be ;04?

Comment: Let's have a big round of applause! Thank you! You are amazing at this stuff! I will include you in my list of things I'm thankful for at the turkey table.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving to you too. Be kind to a stranger, make the world a better place.

Comment: Try to avoid magic numbers like `0.02997`. Create a constant with the value and document its usage.

Comment: @ja72 - I have updated my code to take account of your suggestion (and detect if number of digits after comma was something other than 3). Thanks for the pointer.